# mysql pick up recently date

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have below three dates column in my table  and all are datetime columns:

```
LastUse_Date
LastRecharge_Date
LastUpdate
```

I'd like to know how to compare these three columns and pick up most recently date, and also some records show these fields with one or two columns with null value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function [`greatest()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest).
To deal with `null`s use [`coalesce()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) to return the [minimum datetime possible in MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) which is `'1000-01-01 00:00:00'`.
I assume not all 3 dates can be `null`.

```
select greatest(
  coalesce(LastUse_Date, '1000-01-01 00:00:00'),
  coalesce(LastRecharge_Date, '1000-01-01 00:00:00'), 
  coalesce(LastUpdate, '1000-01-01 00:00:00')
) mostrecentdate
from tablename
```

See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jHVvEGEiKS37NsqJMYMxid/1).